# validating a form in an MVC4 project before it has be submitted

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, unobtrusive-validation, client-side-validation

Would like to get validation working on a form so that it works both before and after submit button has clicked.

Currently the forms has server side validation working correctly this uses a combination of data annotations in the model and unobtrusive jquery validation that gives an error message at the top of the page and highlights the control which is incorrect in some form.

I now need to get it so that similar validation gets displayed as the user enters values into the form before they had a chance to submit an incorrect/incomplete form.

I have looked at a number of packages that implement this type of validation but all have been for MVC 3 (the last one I looked at was DataAnnotationsExtensions.ClientValidation now DataAnnotationsExtensions.MVC3) rather than MVC 4 which the project is being developed in.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: [looks like](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-validation-to-the-model) if you're using DataAnnotations, all you need to do i s include and jquery.validate and jquery.validate.unobtrusive in  your view.

Comment: have a look at [Adding Validation to the Model](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-validation-to-the-model)

Comment: validation already exists in the model and have both of the scripts in scripts folder have added the scripts in a _Layout View in the shared folder using @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/all") have then added the scripts to be bundled in the BundleConfig class in App_Start folder will put code below

Answer (score 0):

```
public class BundleConfig
{
            // For more information on Bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=254725
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/all").Include(
            "~/Scripts/modernizr-*",
             "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",        
            "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*",
            "~/Scripts/custom-ie-enhancements.js"));

        BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
    }
}
```

}